# Grails 2.4.2 and Groovy 2.3.3 bad JSON rendering performance

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I'm trying to improve my Grails project performance. While doing some performance review I find out that JSON parsing is taking more than twice the time that GORM takes. My project uses Groovy 2.3.3 which as said has the fastest JSON serializer in JVM. Is there something special I need to do for my project to use this new Groovy JSON parser? How could I improve Grails JSON rendering performance?

Comment: what now, parsing or rendering?  or both?

Comment: It seems like it is a rendering problem. both respond and render takes a huge amount of time.